# Not able to access wildfly console through HTTP

Tags: java, azure, azure-devops, cloud, wildfly-11

I have a wildfly server on my local. I am able to start it and successfully deploy my application.
But problem is whenever I am trying to access wildlfy console on browser I am getting 404 and same result for my application. But surprisingly I am able to connect to console and deploy resource file by using jboss-cli.bat.

Kinldy take a note, my wildfly version is 11 and I have created management user also. I am able to access default page of wildfly by URL http://localhost:8080

Comment: There should be a log entry with the context name of your application. The web console should be available on http://localhost:9990 assuming the defaults.

Comment: I am seeing below two entries in the logs.
Http management interface listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990/management
Admin console listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990

Comment: That should bind on any address then including localhost. For the application you should see something like: `WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/helloworld-rs' for server 'default-server'` the `/helloword-ts` is the context for your application.